# How are SaaS/Mult-Tenancy apps implementing email notifications (sending and receving)?

Tags: email, pop3, saas, multi-tenant

Given  multi-tenant application, How are vendors implementing email notifications from an email account setup and programming perspective:

**Sending emails** could come from a generic account: eg notifications@VendorName.com or noreply@VendorName.com, this seems reasonable considering reply addresses and lilnks can be contained within the email contents.

**Receiving Emails:** How would an application receive email, for instance; to generate support tickets or assign comments in an email to a project/task. I have seen ID's within the subject and some reply to addresses containing the account name eg: notifications@AccountName.VendorName.com

I realise one can programatically connect to a pop3 server and receive emails and look for the IDs with the subject, but is there a way of setting up and receiving email to **a single** pop3 account from multiple sub-host name email addresses (not sure on terminology there) eg: noreply@AccountName1.VendorName.com or noreply@AccountName2.VendorName.com and check the Account Name from the address? (similar to checking subdomains on a URL)

Any practices, experience, comments or sughestions?

(not sure its relevant, but using C# asp.net-mvc and services etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sending notification emails, we have a notification send to address associated with each account and simply send from our domain to that address.  Our from address is monitored and replies end up in the CSR work queue.

For inbound emails, we use [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) (from the makers of Stack Overflow) for case tracking.  That accepts new cases via email (e.g. cases@mycompany.com).  Tickets are auto-created from the email.  My only complaint there is that the customer needs to check an obscure link for case updates (no "my cases" web portal, but maybe that will come out in an upcoming version of FogBugz).

We have a custom field in FogBugz to indicate the customer the ticket is from.  We could theoretically write a plugin to FogBugz that auto-assigns that using the senders domain, but I guess the CSR's haven't complained loudly enough yet :-)

Comment: Thats interesting, thanks. I am just implemented SmarterTrack for a specific project and it works in a similar way. In the admin you setup the SMTP details for sending and the pop3 details your own "support/cases etc" account. This is great and easily implemented/configured for techies, hoping to find a more user friendly solution?

Comment: @Mark: Funny we just answered each other's questions :-) SmartTracker seems (from reading the home page) to be focused just on the help desk side.  FogBugz includes managing internal work items in addition to customer bug fixes for the development team (though SmartTracker is probably more full featured on the help desk side).  We have the email information tied in to our Account screen that either the customer or CSR can access.  No further config required (we do have a back end component that reads the Account object to get the email address for notification).

Comment: :-) I noticed that too...Yes SmarterTrack is purely help-desk related...I may have a look at FogBugz anyway, have heard some good reviews..

Answer (score 2):

We (at [muHive](http://muhive.com)) are an inbound email/social conversations management product. If you are looking at a handling inbound email or social media conversations from customers, we have an impressive toolset.

For our own outbound needs, the simplest way is to use an Email sending API. Don't bother with SMTP sending by yourself. We use [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses) and have also tried [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com) which gave us additional benefits like delivery status and email parsing.

There are two ways in which you can handle multiple accounts to a catch all email address. If your target system can differentiate between different customers and assign tasks to the correct representatives based on either the content/sender, ask all your customers to send an email to *support@company.com*.

As you rightly said, you could also create *accountName_support@company.com* email addresses and use different accounts on whatever CRM/Support solution use to manage these emails.

Another approach is to have your customers send you an email to *support@company.com* and you use a rule based system (like muHive) to forward these mails to the appropriate account executives based on the customer/account who sent the mail.